# Get data from a single table but treat it as two tables

Tags: sql-server

I have this table:

**AccountingEntry**

```
ID | DateAdded | Credit | Debit | Collections | Withdrawal | WholeSellerId
1  | 2016-01-08| 1000.00| 0.00  | 0.00        | 0.00       | Sample1
2  | 2016-01-08| 0.00   | 200.00| 0.00        | 0.00       | Sample1
3  | 2016-01-08| 0.00   | 0.00  | 300.00      | 0.00       | Sample1
4  | 2016-01-08| 0.00   | 0.00  | 0.00        | 500.00     | Sample1
5  | 2016-01-08| 300.00 | 0.00  | 0.00        | 0.00       | AnotherSample
6  | 2016-01-08| 0.00   | 200.00| 0.00        | 0.00       | AnotherSample
```

What I want to achieve is get the present accountability and previous accountability. The "present accountability" is: **from FromDate to ToDate** and the "previous accountability" is: **whatever sum that has been added before the FromDate**.

I have this statement:

```
with 
cte1 as
(select ae1.WholeSellerId as 'wholeseller', isnull((sum(isnull(ae1.Withdrawals,0)) + sum(isnull(ae1.Credit,0))) - (sum(isnull(ae1.Debit,0)) + sum(isnull(ae1.Collections,0))),0) as 'previous_accountability' 
from AccountingEntry ae1
where ae1.DateAdded < '2016-01-08'
group by WholeSellerId),

cte2 as 
(select ae2.WholeSellerId as 'wholeseller2', isnull((sum(isnull(ae2.Withdrawals,0)) + sum(isnull(ae2.Credit,0))) - (sum(isnull(ae2.Debit,0)) + sum(isnull(ae2.Collections,0))),0) as 'present_accountability' 
from AccountingEntry ae2 
where ae2.DateAdded between '2016-01-08' and '2016-01-09'
group by WholeSellerId)

select cte1.wholeseller as 'wholeseller', isnull(cte1.previous_accountability,0) as 'previous accountabiliy', isnull(cte2.present_accountability,0) as 'present accountability' 
from cte1
full join cte2 on cte1.wholeseller=cte2.wholeseller2
```

The result is like so:

```
wholesellerId  | previous accountability | present accountability
NULL           | 0.00                    | 1000
NULL           | 0.00                    | 100
```

The wholeseller is NULL because in the first table, cte1, there is no record before the FromDate. Can you tell me how to do it that the wholeseller will not be NULL if there is no record in the first table, cte1, then just use the wholesellerId in the second table, cte2? Same thing happens when I use the **LEFT JOIN** instead of **FULL JOIN**.

Comment: Are you only expecting a single row?

Comment: It can have as many row as it can depending on the number of WholeSellerIds. But, it should only have 1 result for each WholeSellerId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use isnull for the id as well:

```
select isnull(cte1.wholeseller, cte2.wholeseller) as 'wholeseller'
```